# XAMPP 5.5.38 virtualhost 403 Access forbidden

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5 with XAMPP 5.5.38 running Apache 2.4

When I enter in the address bar localhost or any other name configured in etc/hosts file, this message shows up:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
```

This is the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # get the server name from the 'host:' header
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ErrorLog "logs/myname-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html"
    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

These are the permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites
drwxrwxr-x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0
drwxrwxr-x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html
-rw-rw-r-- /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html/index.php
```

However, when I **change the order** of the vhosts, localhost (in htdocs) is working and any other sitename is redirected to localhost..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # get the server name from the 'host:' header
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ErrorLog "logs/myname-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html"
    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could someone help me to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: `VirtualHost *:80` is this intended behavior to have them catch the same 'any' domain?

Comment: @Bagus Tesa: yes

Comment: alright, the path here `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sites/%0/public_html` does it has `index.html` or anything resembling it? i'm not sure on osx, but i do worried with `%0` on the path..

Comment: @BagusTesa yes. If I replace %0 with mysitename, do `ServerName mysitename.local` and delete `UseCanonicalName Off`, the site **works.** But I don't know why it doesn't works with %0 in the path

Comment: the `UseCanonicalName Off` wont be a problem i think, as it only direct the apache to construct url based on the host and port provided by the client request header. i suspect the `%0` is the cause. i am unsure what you want to achieve with the `%0` as in *nix environment its used to retrieve the executing file as far as i am aware. are you perhaps trying to have apache match the directory path automatically based on the host name passed to it?

Comment: if you answer yes for my last question: [read this QA and use `VirtualDocumentRoot`](https://serverfault.com/a/291915/321311) hope it helps~ and hey, thank you i just learned what the `%0` do. lol.

Comment: @BagusTesa I replaced DocumentRoot with VirtualDocumentRoot but that didn't work :(

Comment: have you restarted the apache?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes I did.